# MySQL Install on Windows 8.1 hangs at server restart

Tags: mysql, windows, mysql-5.6, windows-8, installation

I have a 64-bit Windows 8.1 machine and would like to install a local database to host some helper application databases. I have attempted this several times with [this version of MySQL (5.6.25 GA)](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/windows/installer/) but it hangs at the server restart during the installation. My internet has been stable each time I have attempted this so from my assumptions, this is not caused with a network drop-out.

---

**EDIT**

After looking through the install logs and reading the MySQL Notifier message. According to those, the Windows Service cannot be found. During the installation, the service was called `MySQL56` but MySQL Notifier says `mysql56`. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Personally, I have never been a fan of the MSI Installer. I always install MySQL using the no-install ZIP file. I have Windows 8.1 running 5.6.21. I am going to install 5.6.24. I'll let you know how it goes.

Comment: I just installed MySQL 5.6.24 with the no-install ZIP on my Windows 8.1 laptop. I have no problems whatsoever.

Comment: I guess there was MySQL installed on the machine, and the service is disabled for it, when you tried to install it you chose the service name as the old one, then continue the installation step, at the final step when MySQL try to start the service it hanged since the service is disabled ( can not be started).

Comment: @RolandoMySQLDBA So just extract to a desired location and run from there?

Silly question, but can i install MySQL Workbench from there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I [mentioned in the comment](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/98159/mysql-install-on-windows-8-1-hangs-at-server-restart/98256#comment177133_98159), I installed MySQL 5.6.24 for Windows.

I have a 4-year-old post in ServerFault ([Installing isolated instance of MySQL on Windows using silent install with .msi](https://serverfault.com/a/234125/69271)) I outline how to install MySQL as a service by hand with

- Custom Folder for MySQL Binaries
- Custom Folder for MySQL Data
- Custom Name for MySQL Service

I also have [SuperUser post on why I personally avoid MSI installs of MySQL](https://superuser.com/questions/461953/mysql-quiet-installation-references-wrong-executable/492875#492875)

I have worked with MySQL Query Browser, MySQL Administrator, and MySQL Workbench the in a much simpler way:

- Just copy the software into the desired folder.
- Create a Windows Shortcut (`.lnk`) for the `.exe` file
- Put the Windows Shortcut (`.lnk`) on the Desktop or Start Menu
- Double Click to Launch

## Give it a Try !!!

Comment: Though your answer didn't explicitly solve my issue, I'm accepting it for others to use.

My problem was that I'd previously tried to install it but had it fail due to a power outage. I had an instance of SQLWriter in my services so had to delete this and all records of MySQL to get the database installed and working.

Many thanks for the help with this issue.